# Has anyone got Icefaces 3.3 app working on Payara 5 / Glassfish 5?

Tags: jsf, icefaces, payara, icefaces-3

We are porting an application over from Glassfish 3.1.2.2 to Payara 5. The application uses Icefaces 3.3.0 which is confirmed to work with JSF 2.1.

We have two options to deploy this in Payara 5, use the built in JSF version 2.3.x which is supposed to be backwards compatible, or bundle JSF 2.1.x along with Icefaces in the war included in the ear.
So far I have tried each of the methods but I have hit problems with both.

When using the server included JSF version 2.3.x as soon as a page does an ajax call (in the icefaces world this is a partial submit) then we see the error:

`javax.faces.FacesException: Cannot add the same component twice: v9oeh233_icefaces_config`

Looking around this normally means that `com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener` has been started twice however in this case that listener isn't included in our `web.xml` and I don't see any errors suggesting that it has been started twice. If I include it in the `web.xml` then it makes no difference we still see the error. The servlet spec set in the `web.xml` was also specified as 2.5 which another thread suggested would stop that listener from being auto initialised by Servlet 3.0.

When bundling JSF 2.1.x I have had to also bundle the weld core jar to get it to work as well as using the whitelist-package functionality to get to a point where it will load the EJB jar project. Once it's started I can visit some of the pages in the application but as soon as I get to one that uses our custom taglib I get the following error:

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.thirddegree.shared.utils.UserHasRoleTagHandler.<init>(javax.faces.view.facelets.TagConfig)`

The class is definitely there and that constructor exists as it all worked on glassfish 3.1.2.2 so it's possibly something to do with class versioning but I can't seem to work out what.

Has anyone tried doing an icefaces 3.3.0 migration to either Payara 5 or Glassfish 5 and if so have you hit similar problems or have any solutions? Also any suggestions for things that I might be able to try?

Many thanks,
Darren